# How to complete authentication required in API call in Cloudera with python programming

Tags: python, authentication, request

Cloudera provides API interface for a user to retrieve information, here is an example of Linux command line:

```
curl -v -k -X GET -u user:password "https://hostname:7183/api/v11/clusters/cluster/services/impala/impalaQueries"
```

As you can see there is authentication in place.

I want to write a program in python to send a request to retrieve the same result.

This is what I did:

```
import requests

url = "https://hostname:7183/api/v11/clusters/cluster/services/impala/impalaQueries"
requests.get(url, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

I receive the following error:
bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

What is wrong here? Can anyone help to sort it out? the expected data is in JSON format.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your url is not valid. change your code to `url = https://hostname:7183/api/v11/clusters/cluster/services/impala/impalaQueries`

Comment: that's not the point. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing on verifying your SSL certificate. Try setting verify=False. From the documentation http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/:

> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set verify to False:
>
> > > requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', verify=False)

so use:

```
requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

You can suppress the waring given like this:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://hostname:7183/api/v11/clusters/cluster/services/impala/impalaQueries"
x = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=('username', 'password'))
print (x.json())
```

This is similar to using the the -k (or --insecure) flag you are passing to cURL.

Comment: Thank you very much and your code helps me to pass the authentication, now how can I retrieve the response after the request? I tried ` response = request.get(url, verify=False, auth=('username', 'password')) ` but error out with no specific error message

Comment: I have updated the example to print the json you can access the json using standard procedures

Comment: no need to load it it is a json object already response.json()